# Finding out the type of invoked method in JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

In this code, prosseek.B#bar() method invokes prosseek.SuperA#foo().

```
package prosseek;

public class SuperA {
    int i = 0;
    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public class B {
    public void bar()
    {
        SuperA a = new SuperA();
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

I need to detect the type of foo() invoked in bar().
I use ASTVisitor to detect the MethodInvocation code (a.foo()), but I'm not sure what should I do in order to get the `SuperA` type from it.

```
ICompilationUnit icu = type.getCompilationUnit();
final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(icu);
parser.setResolveBindings(true); // we need bindings later on
CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

unit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation methodInvocation)
    {
        // ???

        return false;
    }
}
```

### ADDED

I got the hint from JDT fundamentals tutorial.

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
IBinding binding = methodInvocation.resolveTypeBinding();
IType type = (IType)binding.getJavaElement();
if (type == null)
    return false;
```

However, I got null for the return value of binding.getJavaElement();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of taking the type of the *MethodInvocation*, may be you need to take the type from the *Expression*. I have not tested this, but this might help.

```
public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
    Expression exp = node.getExpression();
    ITypeBinding typeBinding = node.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding();
    System.out.println("Type: " + typeBinding.toString());
}
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks. Could you care to explain why "node.getExpression()" binding returns IType, while "node" binding doesn't?

Comment: A method invocation comprises of two nodes : an optional expression and a name. The expression is the one which denotes the class on which the method is being called, whereas the name denotes the method name. Thus in order to get the type of the class being used, we need to check the type binding for the expression. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting a null value from:

`methodInvocation.resolveTypeBinding();`

because you haven't set up your parser correctly. According to the JDT documentation for resolveTypeBinding:

"Resolves and returns the binding for the type of this expression.
Note that bindings are generally unavailable unless requested when the AST is being built."
(http://goo.gl/IAUtR8 )

In order to enable bindings you must call this method on your parser:

`parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);`

Comment: I still get null for `methodInvocation.resolveTypeBinding();` and `methodInvocation.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding();` even after setting `parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);`. I set setBindingsRecovery to true just after `ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);` am I missing something?

Comment: To get bindings, setBindingsRecovery(true) has to be *after* setSource! If you do it before setSource, resolveTypeBinding returns null. Seems that this is per source file setting.

Answer (score 0):

I could use this code to get the IType: find method, find ICompilationUnit, find the class that contains the method.

I think the code is rather dumb, and there might a method to give me the method that returns  IType from IMethod.

```
public boolean visit(MethodInvocation methodInvocation)
{
    //IBinding binding = methodInvocation.resolveTypeBinding();
    IBinding binding = methodInvocation.resolveMethodBinding();
    IMethod method = (IMethod)binding.getJavaElement();
    ICompilationUnit cu = method.getCompilationUnit();
    IType type = null;
    try {
        IType[] types = cu.getTypes();
        if (types.length == 1) {
            type = types[0];
        }
        else {
            for (IType t : types)
            {
                IMethod[] methods = t.getMethods();
                for (IMethod m : methods)
                {
                    if (m == method) {
                        type = t;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (type != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## ADDED

This code works fine with me.

```
public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node)
{
    String methodName = node.getName().toString();
    ITypeBinding typeBinding = node.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding();
    IType type = (IType)typeBinding.getJavaElement();

    System.out.printf("Type %s (method %s) calls %s\n", typeName, methodName, type.getFullyQualifiedName());
    return false;
}
```